# global name 'self' is not defined

Tags: titanium-mobile

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[INFO] logfile = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Todo List\build.log
[DEBUG] C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\builder.py simulator Todo List E:\New SDK C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Todo List com.appcelerator.sample.todo 7 WVGA854
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2340, in <module>
    builder = Builder(project_name,sdk_dir,project_dir,template_dir,app_id)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 355, in __init__
    self.set_java_commands()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 399, in set_java_commands
    commands = java.find_java_commands()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\java.py", line 61, in find_java_commands
    java_home = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(self.javac))
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Note: when i run simple application in titanium studio it throws this error. i am totaly new in titanium.so guys, please help me for solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that environment variable JAVA HOME is not present. The error says that it's not possible to call javac because 'self' is not set. 'self' in this case should be java home.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables

Comment: Er, I think `self` in this case is Python related.

Comment: yeah that might be possible. but missing JAVA_HOME is most common error when setting up titanium as a newbie.